# Matching samples in R

Tags: r

I made up a dataframe to explain my question, my real dataset is much bigger.

```
gene <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
sample <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
expression <- c("5", "6", "8", "3", "5", "7", "7", "8", "9")
data.frame(gene, sample, expression)

  gene sample expression
1    a      a          5
2    b      a          6
3    c      a          8
4    a      b          3
5    b      b          5
6    c      b          7
7    a      c          7
8    b      c          8
9    c      c          9
```

and

```
gene2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
sample2 <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3")
expression2 <- c("5.4", "6.3", "8", "3.2", "5.4", "7.2", "7.1", "8.2", "9.4")
data.frame(gene2, sample2, expression2)

  gene2 sample2 expression2
1     a       1         5.4
2     b       1         6.3
3     c       1           8
4     a       2         3.2
5     b       2         5.4
6     c       2         7.2
7     a       3         7.1
8     b       3         8.2
9     c       3         9.4
```

So I have 2 different dataframes with different sample identifiers. But the expression data (should) be kind of the same. What I want to do is find per sample the closest matching expression   values and report back the corresponding sample identifiers. so it could look something like this:

```
  gene sample sample2 expression expression2
1    a      a       1          5         5.4
2    b      a       1          6         6.3
3    c      a       1          8           8
4    a      b       2          3         3.2
5    b      b       2          5         5.4
6    c      b       2          7         7.2
7    a      c       3          7         7.1
8    b      c       3          8         8.2
9    c      c       3          9         9.4
```

I would think maybe a `roll join` but im kind of lost on this

Comment: Do you want to match expression 1 with expression 2 by forcing `sample` and `sample2` to correspond? (e.g. a=1, b=2, c=3)

Comment: @YacineHajji yes, this is indeed my intention. But it gets hard when there are 20k different genes with. So thats why im looking for a closest match and not a full match.

Comment: There are different types of matching. Poor matching will allow you to keep all rows, strong matching will remove rows hard to match with some methods. Do you need to keep all genes in the end?

Comment: @YacineHajji For this purpose, No I dont need all genes, I just need a reasonable amount to tell that sample a = sample b etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a rolling join with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, expression := as.numeric(expression)]
setDT(df2)[, ":="(sample = unique(df1$sample)[as.numeric(sample2)],
                  gene = gene2,
                  expression = as.numeric(expression2))]


df <- df2[df1, on = .(gene, sample, expression), roll = "nearest"][, gene2 := NULL][]
setcolorder(df, rev(seq_along(df)))
df

#    gene expression sample expression2 sample2
# 1:    a          5      a         5.4       1
# 2:    b          6      a         6.3       1
# 3:    c          8      a           8       1
# 4:    a          3      b         3.2       2
# 5:    b          5      b         5.4       2
# 6:    c          7      b         7.2       2
# 7:    a          7      c         7.1       3
# 8:    b          8      c         8.2       3
# 9:    c          9      c         9.4       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` (to compare genes), `outer` (to create distance matrix) and `apply` (for each row find column which has minimum value). Using `mapply` you can wrap everything together:

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(gene, sample, expression, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(gene2, sample2, expression2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1$expression <- as.numeric(df1$expression)
df2$expression2 <- as.numeric(df2$expression2)
```

code:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  mapply(
    function(x, y){
      j <- apply(
        abs(outer(x$expression, y$expression2, FUN = "-")), 1, which.min
      )
      cbind(x, y[j,])
    },
    split(df1, df1$gene),
    split(df2, df2$gene2),
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
)
```